# Why <font> does not work with java swing?

Tags: java, swing, colors, label

I'm trying to color some words in a JLabel.

Note: i'm not putting <> in non-code parts due to the site not displaying it, but i put it in the code.

If the "myArrayList.get(i)" text is "Test\n test\n" and i go like this

```
String s = "<font color = red>test</font>";
myLabel.setText("<html>" + s + myArrayList.get(i).replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;").replaceAll("\n", "<br/>") + "</html>");
```

The s text gets colored, as it should.

But if i pass "myArrayList.get(i)" containing the "font color = red" + "Test\n test\n" + "/font" and i go again

```
myLabel.setText("<html>" + myArrayList.get(i).replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;").replaceAll("\n", "<br/>") + "</html>");
```

It displays the "font color = red" and "/font" part, without coloring the text.

Comment: It's because you're replacing `<` and `>` with HTML escapes. Remove `.replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;")` if you don't want that.

Comment: `new JLabel("<html><font color=red>Test</font></html>");` works fine for me.  I'm scratching my head over `myArrayList.get(i).replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;")` though, replacing `<` with `&lt;` will make the render engine render the `<` character instead of treating as code element